# Binding to a dependency property of a user control WPF/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My app looks like this:

---

`SectionHeader`

`SectionHeader`

*Content*

`SectionHeader`

*Content*

---

`SectionHeader` is a user control with two dependency properties = Title and Apps.

Title does not change but Apps needs to be bound to the main window view model Apps property. The Apps property is only required for two of the three section headers.

```
<c:SectionHeader DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="SectionResources" Title="RESOURCES"
   Apps="{Binding Path=Apps}" />
```

This is how it is at the moment. The problem is that the Apps don't show up.

In `SectionHeader` the DataContext is set to itself as follows which allows the Title to show up.

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Apps is the ItemsSource for a `ItemsControl` in the UserControl:

```
<ItemsControl
      ItemsSource="{Binding Apps}">
```

---

So my questions are:

- How can I data bind to a UserControl DP?
- Is their an easier way of doing this layout without UserControls?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that Apps is an ObservableCollection of AppsItems.

This is what my DP looks like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AppsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Apps",
  typeof (ObservableCollection<AppsItem>), typeof (SectionHeader),
  new PropertyMetadata(null, OnAppsPropertyChanged));

private static void OnAppsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello!!!");
  var sectionHeader = d as SectionHeader;
  var value = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<AppsItem>;
  sectionHeader.Apps = value;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Give a name to your usecontrol and try binding like this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Apps,ElementName=root}"
```

and root is the name give to your usercontrol

```
  <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Height="350" Width="525"
     x:Name="root">
```

it is element binding to user control which has Apps property

Comment: The Title property is binding just fine - the Apps property is the problem. See question edit.

Comment: are you sure that Apps property what you are binding in "
   Apps="{Binding Path=Apps}" is same type as your dependency property i.e ObservableCollection<AppsItem> . make sure that you are not binding some thing like List<AppsItems> or IEnumerable<AppsItem>.. it should be of type ObservableCollection<AppsItem>

Comment: it worked, but i dont find the reason of not working earlier :/ i had 4 properties in user control. but two of them were working. With this, it started working.. but m curious why it has not been :/

Answer (score 11):

Having tried to repro this from your description and coming across a similar problem I found that the only way I could make it work is to not set the DataContext of the UserControl, and instead use ElementBinding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="thisUC"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="Red" Padding="10">
        <ListBox x:Name="ucList" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=thisUC, Path=UCApps}"/>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The implementation of this UC is trivially simple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public IEnumerable UCApps
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(UCAppsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UCAppsProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Apps.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UCAppsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UCApps", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
    }
}
```

as is the XAML that calls it:

```
<Grid >
    <my:UserControl1 x:Name="ucName" UCApps="{Binding Path=Apps}"/>
</Grid>
```

(I changed the name of `Apps` in your Usercontrol to `UCApps` so I could see what was going on - too many properties with the same name got confusing!)

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for the assistance. This suggestion is similar to bathineni's above with the user control named root. This is what I needed to do in the end - but there was also problems with the collection I was trying to bind.

Answer (score 3):

```
Apps="{Binding Path=Apps}"
```

Binds Apps to itself.

Try following

1) Your ViewModel should be a DataContext of Control, then you can use following

```xml
Apps="{Binding DataContext.Apps}"
```

Also you can use [Snoop](http://snoop.codeplex.com/) utility to find binding issues in real time

Comment: Did not seem to fix it. The Apps DP's Setter in the UserControl is not being fired.

Comment: @reckoner: The setter won't get fired, rather the `Get` and `Set` methods are invoked by the framework. If you need to react to dependency properties being changed you need to add a callback.

Comment: @reckoner: this is why recommended to do not put any logic in getter and setter of DPs, because WPF calling DPs in other way

Comment: Thanks sll, I think its more to do with the interaction between the MainWindow and the UserControl. See question edit as I left out the fact that Apps is an ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
Apps="{Binding Apps}"
```

instead of

```
Apps="{Binding Path=Apps}"
```

in your top level control?

Also, do you get any binding errors in the VS output window when you run the app?

Comment: No binding errors. Apps vs. Path=Apps makes no difference. Something strange is that my Console.WriteLine(..) doesn't fire when placed in the Title getter and setter.